# Yiddish in chassidish versus in yeshivish culture

Tags: yiddish, misnaged

If I understand correctly, both Litvaks and Chassidic people emphasized speaking Yiddish at home before WW2. What changed?

In today's age, why is Yiddish the primary language for Chassidim and not for Litvaks?

Why didn't Yeshivish people decide to continue ensuring the survival of the Yiddish language, like their Chassidic counterparts? (I understand that the shiur/class in many Yeshivish yeshivas is still taught in Yiddish; however, most of these students didn't grow up in a household that spoke Yiddish).

If there are any sources, that would be great.

Comment: I'm not certain this is on-topic.

Comment: I would ask the opposite - what's the rationale for speaking Yiddish?  It doesn't have the advantages of the language of the country you live in (easier to deal with), Hebrew (Leshon Hakodesh and language of the Torah), or even Aramaic (language of part of Tanach, Targum, and the Amoraim).  There's lots of Torah written in Yiddish, but personally if I were going to learn another Jewish language I'd probably pick Arabic to have access to more Rishonim.

Comment: How do you know these facts?

Comment: I have friends in yeshivish circles and chassidish circles. I think Yiddish was taught to keep the jews distinct and insular. I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: @Truthseeker there are so many yeshivish and chassidish circles, so is it possible there are some that it's the other way around?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what your referring to, but you're probably correct. These are my personal observations...

Comment: Yiddish is a form of German that developed over time in Jewish communities. Chassidim stuck with it because they emphasize tradition more.

Comment: There's a lot of culture the yeshivish litvaks kept after the war. I guess chassidim thought Yiddish is a vital part of Judaism.

Comment: There are non-chassidic households that speak Yiddish. Perushim, Briskers and Neturei Karta people speak it, they emphasize these traditional aspects very similarly to Chassidim. Maharil Diskin once said "For all the days of our exile, Yiddish will be spoken!" (In the Footsteps of the Flock, p. 72). Other than that, Yiddish is specially important to Chassidim because it connects them to their Rebbes of present and past generations, to Breslevers in order to understand the original words of R' Nachman, the Noam Elimelech says in Tzetil Koton to review it in Yiddish, among many other examples.

Comment: So essentially it's being used as a buffer to understanding the world around them?

Comment: I can concede that they use as a buffer to the (secular) world around them, but not to understanding it. Or maybe you meant as a medium to understanding their religious world.

Comment: Correct. Ensuring yondering too far off the track is more difficult. Sad.

Comment: As a non-jew learning Yiddish to eventually join them there is nothing sad about it and they are not losing anything of value.

Comment: Lol, good luck being accepted. Watch unorthodox. They can't gracefully leave if needed.

Comment: No thanks. I have better ways to inform myself as an outsider on what happens on hasidic circles than actors on Netflix, that's what learning Yiddish is also for. If you are really into such matters and not just stupid entertainment products, I recommend you watch the recent Zev Brenner interview with the hasidic Ger that left Judaism. Anyways, I'm responsible and mature enough to not make a commitment knowing that I'll leave it.

Comment: I watched that interview. He must have an extreme personality. Good luck acclimating. I'm sure your going to be welcome whatever you go in life.